# Least squares method what is an good error

Tags: numerical-methods, least-squares

Hi I have started using the least squares method and I want to calculate the mean error of my approximation. I use the following formular for calculating the error: $\ \mathcal E = ||A\hat x - y||/\sqrt n$
But how do I know if the error is big or low. Is it good to have a low number on $\ \mathcal E$ or should it be high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\hat{x} - y = \hat{y} - y$ is the difference vector, and $\varepsilon$ is its norm divided by the constant $\sqrt{n}$. 
So $\varepsilon$ is a non-negative number. The smaller $\varepsilon$, the better the approximation.

Comment: Thanks is it a way to use this formula to find how much the approximation differ for example I want to find if the approximation is between $\pm 5 \% $

Comment: You are aware that the difference vector is a $n$-dimensional vector, while $\varepsilon$ is a number? It depends on what kind of norm you use, what meaning a non-zero value of $\varepsilon$ might have. (For a zero value it is a perfect fit).